# Verification: Showing that an integral goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm pretty sure this is correct but I've spent a couple days doing it the wrong way (I once tried to invoke a mean value theorem for complex analysis before realizing it doesn't exist) so a quick verification would be appreciated.

Prove: Define $f(t) = e^{-(Re^{it})^2} iRe^{it}$. Show that as $R \to \infty$, the integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} f(t) dt \to 0$.

First note:

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} f(t) dt = 
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} iRe^{-R^2 \cos 2t} e^{-iR^2 \sin 2t} e^{it}dt$$

so that

$$ \Bigg\lvert \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} f(t) dt \Bigg\rvert \leq 
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} Re^{-R^2 \cos 2t} dt$$

Let $g(t) = Re^{-R^2 \cos 2t}$. Since $g$ is continuous on $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$, there must be some antiderivative $G$ such that $G'(t) = g(t).$ Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} Re^{-R^2 \cos 2t} dt = G\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}\Big) - G(0) = \frac{G\big(\frac{\pi}{4}\big) - G(0)}{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\pi}{4}$$

By the mean value theorem, the first first expression is equal to $g(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in (0, \frac{\pi}{4})$. Thus,

$$ G\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}\Big) - G(0) = \frac{\pi}{4} g(\alpha) = \frac{\pi}{4} Re^{-R^2 \cos 2\alpha}$$

Since $\alpha \in (0, \frac{\pi}{4})$, we know $0 < \cos 2\alpha < 1$ is fixed, so that

$$ \Bigg\lvert \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} f(t) dt \Bigg\rvert \leq \frac{\pi}{4} Re^{-bR^2}$$

for some positive $b$, and the right hand side clearly goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty.$

Comment: It's not clear to me why $\alpha$ should be independent of $R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has a gap. Note that $\alpha$ relies on $R$ and should be denoted by $\alpha_R$. It may happen that $\alpha_R\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}$ rapidly as $R\rightarrow \infty$. Then $\exp(-R^2\cos 2\alpha_R)$ will no longer be small.

Answer (score 2):

For the integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}Re^{-R^{2}\cos2t}dt,$$ we
let $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-2t$ and rewrite it as $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-R^{2}\sin x}dx.$$
Observe that for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\sin x\geq\frac{x}{2}$.
Therefore 
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-R^{2}\sin x}dx\leq\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}Re^{-\frac{R^{2}}{2}x}dx.
$$
The integral on the RHS can be integrated directly and it can be shown
that it converges to $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Simple but brilliant, thank you.